# How to get the intermediate values/steps of an animation of an DependencyProperty?

Tags: c#, animation, windows-store-apps, dependency-properties

I am working on Windows Store 8.1 App project and would like to create a custom progressbar/gauge control. The class internally measures some values and displays them as text and as progressbar/gauge. Value changes should be animated:

```
public class CustomGauge : UserControl{

    private static readonly DependencyProperty SpeedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Speed", typeof(double), typeof(CustomGauge), new PropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(SpeedChanged)));
    private double Speed{
        get { return (double)GetValue(SpeedProperty ); }
        set { SetValue(SpeedProperty , value); }
    }

    // In CustomGauge.xaml a TextBlock uses a Binding to Speed to display the value


    private static void SpeedChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
        CustomGauge gauge = d as CustomGauge;
        if (gauge != null)
            gauge.DrawSpeed();
    }

    private void OnSpeedChanged(double newSpeedValue) {
        DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation();
        animation.EnableDependentAnimation = true;
        animation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5));
        animation.To = newSpeedValue;

        PowerEase easing = new PowerEase();
        easing.Power = 5.0;
        easing.EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseOut;

        animation.EasingFunction = easing;

        Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
        storyboard.Children.Add(animation);
        Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, this);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, "Speed");

        storyboard.Begin();
    }

    private void DrawSpeed() {
        ...
    }
}
```

While the text of the XAML TextBlock which uses a binding to "Speed" is animated the gauge/progressbar just jumps from the old value to the new one without animation. This is because SpeedChanged(...) is only called once with the new value and not for every intermediate value of the animation from old to new value.

How can I solve this and use the animation to change the gauge/progressbar as well?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is create a "Step Size" and "Step Time" for your animation. It will take the value given, find the difference, and cut that difference into chunks, animating each.

Note: I am using the [WinRTXamlToolkit](http://WinRTXamlToolkit.codeplex.com) for their awesome [StoryBoard Extensions](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinRTXamlToolkit/AwaitableUI/StoryboardExtensions.cs). It's arguably unnecessary, and if you choose to not incorporate the whole library, it's easy to add that one extension.

```
// Set this to something sensible for your speeds.
// You may want to have it be calculated on the fly,
// Such as by doing an even distribution of steps,
// Possibly with a minimum value for a step to be. Up to you.
private const double StepSize = 5; 

private const double StepTime = 1.5;

private async void OnSpeedChanged(double newSpeedValue) {

    DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation();
    animation.EnableDependentAnimation = true;

    PowerEase easing = new PowerEase();
    easing.Power = 5.0;
    easing.EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseOut;

    animation.EasingFunction = easing;

    Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
    storyboard.Children.Add(animation);
    Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, this);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, "Speed");

    // You may want to have this be an absolute value and store the sign
    // in case there is both a positive and negative change in speed
    var difference = newSpeedValue - Speed;

    for(double stepValue = Speed + StepSize; i < difference; i += StepSize)
    {
        animation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(StepTime));
        animation.To = stepValue;

        await storyboard.BeginAsync();
    }

    // do the last one
    animation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(StepTime));
    animation.To = newSpeedValue;

    await storyboard.BeginAsync();
}
```

One last thing to note is that I've made OnSpeedChanged async. To SpeedChanged method, it will just "set it and forget it" in that it will call it and immediately continue. If your speed changes regularly, you'll need to do some chaining effect such as cancelling the last animations with a CancellationToken. Another option is to keep a queue of the running animation tasks and run them sequentially. This may or may not be a good idea for a number of reasons.

Hope this helps and happy coding!